# C# pretends to change registry?

Tags: c#, windows, registry

Let me preface this by saying I have no idea what's happening. I simply want to change a registry key from `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`. I wrote some C# to quickly change it and it seems to work, except for when I refresh regedit to view the changes.

```
try {   
     var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE");
     key = key.OpenSubKey(@"ServOr", true);

     //SHOWS localhost
     MessageBox.Show(key.GetValue(@"HOST").ToString());
     key.SetValue(@"HOST", @"127.0.0.1", RegistryValueKind.String);

     //SHOWS 127.0.0.1
     MessageBox.Show(key.GetValue(@"HOST").ToString());

     key.Close();
     //Regedit still shows localhost
} catch (Exception exception) {
     MessageBox.Show(exception.ToString());
}
```

The particularly strange part that is if you run it a second time, both Messageboxes will show `127.0.0.1` although the registry still has `localhost`. Visual studio is running with admin privileges. The registry allows full control to admins.

Comment: Are you running a 32-bit process on a 64-bit machine?  Check for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ServOr`

Comment: The 64bit thing is probably the answer, since registry key sets are always visible to other programs immediately. You don't need to initiate a registry flush or anything like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run a 32-bit process in 64-bit Windows, Windows will hide the 64-bit registry and Program Files directory (among other things) from the program.  When a 32-bit program access the registry, it will show it a subset of the registry in the `Wow6432Node` path.

So, your key is in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ServOr`

Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64 and [this post on MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/92f962d6-7f5e-4e62-ac0a-b8b0c9f552a3/issue-reading-x64-registry-keys?forum=netfx64bit)